# How to avoid duplicates values while inserting data in database using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I'm building a program where the user imports an excel file (by asp.net C#), and What I want to do is, an insert in my web application where if the user puts the same data that already is inserted it shows a message saying that it fails

here's the code:

```
public partial class Inserir : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Dados values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"','"+TextBox4.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

```
Mov. Date   Value Date   move description   Value in EUR
28/02/2001 - 20/04/2019 - Fh123iasdasd    - 20119  
28/02/2001 - 20/04/2019 - Fh123iasdasd12  - 20119 
28/02/2001 - 20/04/2019 - Fh123iasdasd    - 20119 <--- Dont want this line
```

I don't want the column "move description" to be able of, having the same name as others

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a unique key on the field in the database. Any attempt to add a duplicate in another record should then throw an exception.

Comment: It worked, but im thinking if isn't There's no way the user can have another opportunity to write again giving an error as an user and not a exception as a programmer

Comment: On the contrary, catch the exception, handle it by telling the user what the problem was and they should be free to change the value and have another go.

Comment: I Did that And it worked but I have 1 more question can I do it for an full row?

Comment: @PedroPereira you can do it for ANY combination of the columns in the row, including all the columns.   So yes.

Comment: @PedroPereira, yes my comment is meant to address your other question.   Just try it.

Comment: @TabAlleman Won't Work cause my first column has 2 rows with exacly the same date in my column named "date mov"... I dont want to "unique" a single column I want that  a record can't be the exacly equal to another record

Comment: You can create a composite key, which lists a number of fields in combination that have to be unique.

Comment: @PedroPereira what I suggested WILL work, you just aren't understanding what I'm saying.  You can put a UNIQUE constraint on a combination of columns, not just a single column.  You can even put it on ALL of the rows in the column to make sure that if there is ANY difference between one row and another, it will be allowed.

Comment: @TabAlleman Ok, tried that and it appears this expection: System.InvalidOperationException: 'A Column 'Data Mov.' não permite DBNull.Value...

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on the table that includes the column(s) that must be unique. This will prohibit duplicate entries regardless of the method used to insert the data.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableName_ColumnName] ON [dbo].[TableName]
(
    [ColumnName] ASC
)
```

Comment: It worked, but im thinking if isn't There's no way the user can have another opportunity to write again giving an error as an user and not a exception as a programmer

Comment: @PedroPereira you could probably handle that in a try/catch/finally block